# min cost path in matrix when degree of movement is eight

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, backtracking

A variant of this problem ....

Given a cost matrix `cost[][]` and a position `(m, n)` in `cost[][]`, write a function that returns cost of minimum cost path to reach `(m, n)` from `(0, 0)`. Each cell of the matrix represents a cost to traverse through that cell. Total cost of a path to reach `(m, n)` is sum of all the costs on that path (including both source and destination). You can only traverse down, right and diagonally lower cells from a given cell, i.e., from a given cell `(i, j)`, cells `(i+1, j)`, `(i, j+1)` and `(i+1, j+1)` can be traversed

[Problem link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-6-min-cost-path/)

If we were allowed to traverse in all possible directions rather than the three allowed       here ..How to solve this variant now ..
I try to think of backtracking but its not working ..
Any ideas !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) in a weighted graph, and is solveable by [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) (if all costs are positives) or [Bellman-Ford Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm).

In here, the graph is `G=(V,E)`, where `V={(x,y) | (x,y) is a cell in the matrix}`, and `E={(u,v) | can move from cell u to cell v}`. 

 Your weight function will be 
`w((x1,y1),(x2,y2)) = cost[x2][y2]` for every edge in the graph.

Note that both algorithm will fail if the graph has a 'negative cycle' - because there is no such thing as minimal cost in such graphs.